# outlook displaying css code in email signature

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, signature

trying to figure out why on earth Outlook is displaying my CSS code above my html email signature?

It seems to strip out the actual style tag but display the code as text?

perfectly fine in other email clients.

Any ideas?

code:

```
<body>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<style>
  a.link{margin:0;padding:0;border:none !important;text-decoration:none !important;}
table,tr,td,a,span{font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
.appleGreyLinks{color: #666666 !important; text-decoration: none;}
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {color: inherit !important;text-decoration: none !important;font-size: inherit !important;font-family: inherit !important;font-weight: inherit !important;line-height: inherit !important;}
</style>
<!--[if mso]>
<style>
    * {
        font-family: sans-serif !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='address=no' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='email=no' />

<table width='320' id="sig" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<tr>
    <td width="60" valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;width:60px;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <a href='mailto:info@...
and so on
```

Here's the code incorrectly displayed in outlook before the main part of the email signature...

[image: outlook]

Comment: What type/version of Outlook are you talking about?

Comment: cause outlook has a nasty habit of rewriting things to suit itself. When coding webmail for outlook the best practice is to use inline styles for everything and do not attempt to use style tags.

Comment: yeah @scrappedcola thing is there is some CSS there that can't be inlined (as far as I'm aware), the apple data detector stuff. I'm not worried if Outlook ignores the CSS but it's actively displaying it! So stupid.

Comment: Think I have fixed it myself, for anyone with the same issue it seems to be as the style tags were not inside header tags <head> put styles in here </head>

Comment: 2016 @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score 0):

you have your CSS styling in body the  of the email.

All your non-inline CSS should be moved to the head

```
<head>
 <style>
   *YOUR CSS HERE*
 </style>
</head>
<body>
*YOUR CONTENT HERE*....
```